# simple PHP Form with Honeypot - action on another page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple PHP form that has all code on 1 page.

I want to seperate the Contact.php form page from the send.php action by creating a seperate PHP page.

If I combine the code into one page it all works, but if I seperate them into 2 pages, it does not work. Any help would be appreciated on how to seperate the PHP Form from the PHP script.

The problem with the below code is that when I hit send, it goes to send.php, but is blank and does not execute the php form script.

**Example of what I want:**

Contact.php

```
<!--form-->
<form method="post" action="send.php" id="myform">

<?php echo $error; ?>
<?php echo $success; ?>

<input  name="name" type="text" id="name"  class="form1" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="toUpper(this.value); if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name'; }" value="Name" />

<input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form1" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; }" value="Email" />

<input name="email_confirm" type="text" id="email_confirm" class="form2" value="<?php echo $email_confirm; ?>" />

<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Message') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Message'; }" value="Message"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>

<p class="form1"><input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" /></p>

</form>
<!--end form-->
```

Send.php

```
<?php
//fields
    $link_address   = 'home.html'; // page to redirect to home page
    $honeypot   = '';
    $error      = '';
    $name       = 'Name';
    $email      = 'Email';
    $comments   = 'Message';

    if(isset($_POST['contactus'])) {

    $honeypot   = $_POST['email_confirm'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];

// honeypot
if($honeypot)
  exit(1);


//error messages
    if(trim($name) == 'Name') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Name</div>';
    } else if(trim($name) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Name</div>';

    } else if(trim($email) == 'Email') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Email</div>';
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Email</div>';

    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need a valid email</div>';

    } else if(trim($comments) == 'Message') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">A Message is required</div>';
    } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">A Message is required</div>';

    }
    if($error == '') {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
    }
//email address
    $address = "email@example.com";
//email message     
    $e_subject = 'Web Message from: ' . $name . '.';
    $e_body = "From:    $name\nEmail:   $email \r\n\nMessage:\n$comments\n\n\n";

    $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;
    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
    {
//success html page response
     echo "<div id='succsess_page'>";
     echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p>Thank you. The following was sent to us. <br/><br/>$name<br/><br/>$email<br/><br/>$comments</p>";
     echo "<a href='$link_address'>CLOSE THIS MESSAGE</a>";
     echo "</div>";
     } else echo "Error. Mail not sent";
    }
}
    if(!isset($_POST['contactus']) || $error != '') // Do not edit.
    {

?>
<?php }

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.
return(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,12})$/",$email));
}

?>
```

This is what is what is working if I keep it on the same page:

**Working code**

Contact.php

```
<?php
//fields
    $link_address   = 'home.html'; // page to redirect to home page
    $honeypot   = '';
    $error      = '';
    $name       = 'Name';
    $email      = 'Email';
    $comments   = 'Message';

    if(isset($_POST['contactus'])) {

    $honeypot   = $_POST['email_confirm'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];

// honeypot
if($honeypot)
  exit(1);


//error messages
    if(trim($name) == 'Name') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Name</div>';
    } else if(trim($name) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Name</div>';

    } else if(trim($email) == 'Email') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Email</div>';
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need your Email</div>';

    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">Need a valid email</div>';

    } else if(trim($comments) == 'Message') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">A Message is required</div>';
    } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
        $error = '<div class="error_message">A Message is required</div>';

    }
    if($error == '') {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
    }
//email address
    $address = "email@example.com";
//email message     
    $e_subject = 'Web Message from: ' . $name . '.';
    $e_body = "From:    $name\nEmail:   $email \r\n\nMessage:\n$comments\n\n\n";

    $msg = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;
    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
    {
//success html page response
     echo "<div id='succsess_page'>";
     echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p>Thank you. The following was sent to us. <br/><br/>$name<br/><br/>$email<br/><br/>$comments</p>";
     echo "<a href='$link_address'>CLOSE THIS MESSAGE</a>";
     echo "</div>";
     } else echo "Error. Mail not sent";
    }
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['contactus']) || $error != '') // Do not edit.
    {

?>
<!--form-->
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">

<?php echo $error; ?>

<input  name="name" type="text" id="name"  class="form1" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="toUpper(this.value); if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name'; }" value="Name" />

<input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form1" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Email'; }" value="Email" />

<input name="email_confirm" type="text" id="email_confirm" class="form2" value="<?php echo $email_confirm; ?>" />

<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Message') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Message'; }" value="Message"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>

<p class="form1"><input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit" /></p>

</form>
<!--end form-->

<?php }

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.
return(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,12})$/",$email));
}

?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well it makes sense that `send.php` is returning a blank page... _you're not outputting any HTML aside from potential error messages_. Are you sure it's not sending emails either?

Comment: @sjagr it is not sending emails. I am trying to get the data to process on the send.php and echo the response back on the contact.php page